# grep command on Solaris 9

Tags: shell, grep, solaris

I faced a strange behavior of a grep command on Solaris 9.
For example , I have a host file with two lines:

1.1.1.1 host

1.2.3.4 host-MY

I'd like to grep the line contains host string only (not the other line that contain host-MY)

I use:
grep -Fxq host /etc/hosts

but I receive

grep: illegal option -- F

grep: illegal option -- q

grep: illegal option -- x

in spite of the fact that this options I can find in grep manual on my Solaris machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not calling the good `grep` executable.
Run `which grep` to know which one you are running.
On my Solaris box, the official `grep` is in:

```
> which grep
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep
```

The man page on my Solaris box refers to both `/usr/bin/grep` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`. Only the latest supports these options.

Comment: Thanks, I found on my Solaris what you meant