# Using cut and grep commands in unix

Tags: bash, unix, grep, cut

I have a file (file1.txt) with text as:

```
aaa,,,,,
aaa,10001781,,,,
aaa,10001782,,,,
bbb,10001783,,,,
```

My file2 contents are:

```
11111111
10001781
11111222
```

I need to search second field of file1 in file2 and delete the line from file1 if pattern is matching.So output will be:

```
aaa,,,,,
aaa,10001782,,,,
bbb,10001783,,,,
```

Can I use grep and cut commands for this?

Answer (score 8):

This prints lines from file1.txt only if *the second field* is not in file2:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1; next;} !a[$2]' file2 file1.txt
aaa,,,,,
aaa,10001782,,,,
bbb,10001783,,,,
```

#### How it works

This works by reading file2 and keeping track of all lines seen in an associative array `a`.  Then, lines in file1.txt are printed only if its column 2 is not in `a`.  In more detail:

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=1; next;}`

  When reading `file2`, set `a[$1]` to `1` to signal that we have seen the value on this line.  We then instruct awk to skip the rest of the commands and start over on the `next` line.

  This section is only run for file2 because file2 is listed first on the command line and `FNR==NR` only when we are reading the first file listed on the command line. This is because `FNR` is the number of lines read from the current file and `NR` is the total number of lines read so far.  These two are equal only for the first file.
- `!a[$2]`

  When reading file1.txt, `a[$2]` evaluates to true if column 2 was seen in file2.  Since `!` is negation, `!a[$2]` evaluates to true when column 2 was not seen.  When this evaluates to true, the line is printed.

#### Alternative

This is the same logic, expressed in a slightly different style, as suggested in the comments by Tom Fenech:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next;} !($2 in a)' file2 file1.txt
aaa,,,,,
aaa,10001782,,,,
bbb,10001783,,,,
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.as jurgemaister pointed that  all command versions in my solaris are pointing to old folder '/usr/bin/'.Hence i get error as "awk: syntax error near line 1,awk: bailing out near line 1"

Comment: Try running `which -a awk gawk`. See if you have a newer awk installed.

Comment: @user1768029 OK.  In place of the default awk, try running `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`.

Comment: I would have probably gone with simply setting the key in the array `a[$1];` then using `$2 in a` but either way works. Nice explanation anyway.

Comment: @TomFenech Very good; I added code with your approach to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Soulution with grep

```
$ grep -vf file2 file1.txt
aaa,,,,,
aaa,10001782,,,,
bbb,10001783,,,,
```

John1024's awk soulution would be faster for large files though.

Comment: I get error as - "grep: illegal option -- f". I am using bash shell.Can we use this command in bash ?

Comment: Which OS and which version of grep do you use?

Comment: SunOS boc02 5.10 Generic_144488-12 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245973/grep-command-on-solaris-9

Comment: Currently its pointing to  path - /usr/bin/grep  . Is there anyway i can change it to - /usr/xpg4/bin/grep or is it done only by unix admin?

Comment: @user1768029 Put `alias grep=/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` in your `.bash_profile`, then open your terminal again.

Comment: Or just update your `PATH` to have `/usr/xpg4/bin` before `/usr/bin`.  Usually this is set in your `.profile` or similar.

Comment: This assumes that the field cannot occur as a substring of an unwanted field, and that it will not occur in another column than the one you intended to search.  For these reasons, the Awk solution is much superior.

Comment: I never said that the awk version wasn't better, in fact I pointed out that it is indeed faster, but OP asked for a solution with grep, so I provided one for reference. It's not downright wrong, so I hardly feel it's worth a downvote.